# Ubuntu software center - Ubuntu 18.04.3 - wont update components

Tags: 18.04, updates, software-center

Ubuntu software center comes with notification to update but then refuses to update. It seems that update itself is broken.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

[image: 1st problem]

when trying to 'refresh' the list... getting:

[image: 2nd problem]

Comment: Are you using flatpacks?

Comment: Looked up. Have `flatpak` - remembering trying something along the line (trying out some apps via flatpack install). Thought it is `flatpack` but I am guessing that's wrong spelling.

Comment: following the hint. Tried flatpak update. Here's result (still some error). http://txt.do/1olkz

Comment: https://gitlab.com/freedesktop-sdk/freedesktop-sdk/issues/886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a definite answer. More a set of hints to possibly remedy a situation.

Helpful:

- http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/available-runtimes.html
- http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html
- https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1766

Attempts to fix:

Remove possibly not needed

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Explain to flatpak where to get stuff

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

kill previous error of not having platforms

```
flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform//19.08
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Platform//3.34
```

update

```
flatpak update --system 
flatpak update --user
```

these brought flatpak installation to no errors.

However it did not fix 'Ubuntu software center' notification. It still insists that gnome application platform is not installed in spite of:

```
$ flatpak install --system flathub org.gnome.Platform//3.34
Skipping: org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34 is already installed
```

at this point I am suspecting that software center does not see flatpak info correctly.

More hints welcome.

Edit 30/11:

After installing some app from software center, the update notification disappeared from software centre. **Issue that was at the beginning is now resolved**. Flatpak upgrade did resolve the problem.

The remaining question is how to refresh software center after the flatpak update without installing something.